# setTimeout for css not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I've added `setTimeout` to a couple of functions, in one it is running fine but in another it doesn't seem to run at all. I can't tell why as it's exactly the same. Please find below my code, any help would be appreciated.

It's the setTimeout line I'm looking at.This one works fine.

```
var fctyhov = function (z) {
    $(deptmts[i]).hover(
        function(){
            $(fcultys[z]).stop(true).animate({color: col1});
            setTimeout(function(){$(z).css("text-shadow", tsh1);},100);},
        function(){
            $(fcultys[z]).stop(true).animate({color: col3});
            setTimeout(function(){$(z).css("text-shadow", tsh2);},100);}
    );
};
```

But this one doesn't

```
var facdth = function (y,x,w) {
    $(y).hover(
        function(){
            $(x).stop(true).fadeTo("fast", 1);
            $(w).stop(true).delay().animate({color:col1});
            $(y).stop(true).animate({color: col1});
            setTimeout(function(){$(y).css("text-shadow", tsh1);},100);},
        function(){
            $(x).stop(true).fadeTo("slow", 0);
            $(w).stop(true).delay().animate({color:col2});
            $(y).stop(true).animate({color: col3});
            setTimeout(function(){$(y).css("text-shadow", tsh2);},100);}
    );
};
```

**edit**
I've added a plugin which allows .animate({color}) to work. These lines are working fine.

Comment: The most probable problem is that JS is not able to reach that line of code, i.e., there is some other bug. See if any exception is thrown.

Comment: @SidharthMudgal: I thought that might be why, but the other three lines before the `setTimeout` line run fine and if I remove the `setTimeout` line then the function works fine. No errors show up either.

Comment: Its the animate({color}) thats causing error in jquery.

Comment: @deach: Sorry I forgot to mention I've added a plugin which allows animation of text color, which is working fine.

Comment: Did you try using `console.log(...)` inside delayed function and after `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with `tsh1` or `tsh2`. Did you try outputting something from the callbacks as nrodic suggested? By the way, where did those function and var names come from?!

Comment: .... ah sorry I think I might have made a mistake it's the other way around. The one I said is working, actually isn't and the one I said isn'r working actually is. I think I need to have another look at this. @nrodic: Thanks I will try using `console.log()` and see what it comes up with.

Comment: @bfavaretto: `tsh1` and `tsh2` seem to be working fine as I'm calling them in other functions and it works.... as for the names.... I came up with them, sorry I should have renamed them before posting them here.

Comment: It must be something not defined properly; your code seems to work properly if everything is defined. See http://jsfiddle.net/WpNZp/. (Assuming jQuery UI 1.9.1 for color animation; if it's another plugin, try that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the above comments and help. Looking at this again in the morning when I wasn't tired it became clearer. The issue I had was in the first statement, which I thought was working.

Where I was calling `$(z).css` in the `setTimout` function this should have been `$(fcultys[z]).css`. This was a stupid mistake, please see below for my working code.

```
var fctyhov = function (z) {
    $(deptmts[i]).hover(
        function(){
            $(fcultys[z]).stop(true).animate({color: col1});
            setTimeout(function(){$(fcultys[z]).css("text-shadow", tsh1);},100);},
        function(){
            $(fcultys[z]).stop(true).animate({color: col3});
            setTimeout(function(){$(fcultys[z]).css("text-shadow", tsh2);},100);}
    );
};
```